# Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

This occurs when I install specific packages, even if I run as admin; for this case specifically I was running

```
pip install shapash
```

But would get this error

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 
'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\~umba\\core\\runtime\\_nrt_python.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Also tried

```
python -m pip install shapash --user
```

As suggested by another post and variations such as --force-reinstall. Does anybody have a solution to this?

Comment: Where are the `~` characters coming from in that path?  Why are there two of them?  Dows Windows know how to handle them?

Comment: The `~umba` directory is from an interrupted or failed upgrade of `numba`. The easiest thing to do is quit all running Python processes, then go into the `site-packages` directory and delete all the folders that start with `~`. You can then do a clean reinstall of the packages.

Comment: @MattDMo didn't know that's what the `~` represents. Deleting and reinstalling did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Had the same issue in VS Code; deleting all the folders that start with ~ worked for me as well; thanks MattDMo.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this error by running VS Code as **Administrator.**

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I tried to run in administrator prompt, but that did not work either. But in my case, I had python running. After I closed python, I re-ran PIP and it installed successfully. I was trying to install pandas-market-calendars.

Answer (score -1):

go to your virtual environment folder. open up your pyenv.cfg and change the 'include-system-site-packages = false' to true
save it and please try again